# How to link image in canvas to object

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have the following class:

```
class Sapo
{
   private Image imgSapo;

   public int IdSapo { get; }

   public Sapo(int id)
   {
       imgSapo = new Image();
       IdSapo = id;
   }

   public Image show
   {
      get 
      {
        imgSapo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Imagens/sapo.png", UriKind.Absolute));
        imgSapo.Width = 56;
        imgSapo.Height = 56;

        return imgSapo;
      }
  }
}
```

And I have a method where I create a thread passing an instance of each object of class Sapo:

```
public void CriarSapos()
{
   Thread th;

   int sapos = int.Parse(txt_sapos.Text);

   Sapo[] arraySapos = new Sapo[sapos];

   for (int i = 0; i < sapos; i++)
   {
       th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadImageSapo));
       th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
       th.IsBackground = true;
       arraySapos[i] = new Sapo(th.ManagedThreadId);
       th.Start(arraySapos[i]);
   }
}
```

The method responsible for inserting the images on the canvas:

```
public void ThreadImageSapo(object obj)
{
   Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
   {
       Sapo _sapo = (Sapo)obj;

       double max_x = _canvas.ActualWidth - _sapo.show.Width;
       double max_y = _canvas.ActualHeight - _sapo.show.Height;

       Canvas.SetLeft(_sapo.show, rnd.NextDouble() * max_x);
       Canvas.SetTop(_sapo.show, rnd.NextDouble() * max_y);

       _canvas.Children.Add(_sapo.show);

   });
}
```

My objective is that I want to check the collision of images in the canvas and destroy the thread in which the object of that image consists

My question is: How can I get the respective object of the canvas image?

Comment: If you already have access to the Sapo instances, can you just get the Image from the show property? Like you are already doing when adding the Images to the canvas in the first place?

Comment: @Zack 
I want to check the collision of images and destroy the thread in which the object of that image consists

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should generally not create UI elements in code behind, especially in a non-UI thread. Change you Sapo class so that it hold a BitmapImage in a property, instead of an Image control. Also make sure to call `Freeze()` on the BitmapImage to make it cross-thread accessible.

```
public class Sapo
{
    public int IdSapo { get; private set; }
    public double Width { get; private set; }
    public double Height { get; private set; }
    public BitmapImage Image { get; private set; }

    public Sapo(int id)
    {
        IdSapo = id;
        Width = 56;
        Height = 56;
        Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Imagens/sapo.png"));
        Image.Freeze();
    }
}
```

Now when you add the image to a Canvas, create an Image control and assign the BitmapImage like this:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    var sapo = (Sapo)obj;
    var image = new Image
    {
        Source = sapo.Image,
        Width = sapo.Width,
        Height = sapo.Height
    };

    double maxX = _canvas.ActualWidth - image.Width;
    double maxY = _canvas.ActualHeight - image.Height;

    Canvas.SetLeft(image, rnd.NextDouble() * maxX);
    Canvas.SetTop(image, rnd.NextDouble() * maxY);

    _canvas.Children.Add(image);
});
```

This still creates an Image control in code behind, but in the UI thread. A better solution might be to use an ItemsControl with a Canvas as ItemsPanel.

Comment: Ok, but how this can help me to associate this Bitmapimage to an object Sapo?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. The BitmapImage is a property of class Sapo.

Comment: My objective is that I want to check the collision of images in the canvas and destroy the thread in which the object of that image consists

Comment: Ok, why don't you tell us about that in your original question? One solution would be to bind the Image position to x/y properties in the Sapo class. Anyway, an answer to that is beyond the scope of this question.